# Printing directly on the Python interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm typing the following code from the "GA tech intro to Python class" into the python-3 interpreter:

```
>>>grades = [100,95,93,91,90,89,87,87,85,85,84,82]
>>>sum = 0
>>>count = 0
>>>for grade in grades:
...    count = count + 1
...    sum = sum + grade
...print(sum/count)
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    print(sum/count)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Since I'm on the interpreter, should I use the `print` function any differently?

Comment: the print should be inside the for loop, and also as a reminder: The most "Pythonic" way is to use 4 spaces per indent level

Comment: @Rebc3sp I agree the `print` statement should be inside the for loop, but if he wants to prin the result after running the loop, then see below answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the for-loop, enter an empty line to get back to the interpreter prompt `>>>`, then enter the `print` statement.

Entering the `for` statement puts you into a multi-line entry mode that can't go beyond the end of the for-loop body, so assuming you want the `print` statement outside the loop body, you have to get out of the multi-line entry mode before you can enter it.